# Condensing Duplicate Entries in Data Table Columns (R)

Tags: r, data.table

Take the following Data Table with just a single column. It has a column filled with character entries, many of which but not all of which are duplicates. Is there any way I can take this column and easily eliminate any duplicates so that I have a list of all items? I want to take this:

```
d1
       V1
 1:  12 W
 2: 432 N
 3: 37 SE
 4:  12 W
 5: 438 E
 6: 432 N
 7:  12 W
 8: 432 N
 9: 432 N
10: 37 SE
11:  12 W
12:  33 E
```

and make condense it to this

```
d2
      V1
1:  12 W
2: 432 N
3:  33 E
4: 37 SE
5: 438 E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution in base would be:

```
d2 <- unique(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
d2 <- d1 %>% distinct(.)
d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything after whitespace and use `duplicated` to keep only the unique values.

```
df[!duplicated(sub('\\s.*', '', df$V1)), , drop = FALSE]

#      V1
#1   12 W
#2  432 N
#3  37 SE
#5  438 E
#12  33 E
```

If you are using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[!duplicated(sub('\\s.*', '', V1))]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("12 W", "432 N", "37 SE", "12 W", "438 E", 
"432 N", "12 W", "432 N", "432 N", "37 SE", "12 W", "33 E")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```